# Cannot use <float> in python. can anyone please explain i have tried to troubleshoot

Tags: python, jupyter

```
# % that passed math.
passing_math_percentage = passing_math_count / float(student_count) * 100
print(passing_math_percentage)
# % that passed reading.
passing_reading_percentage = passing_reading_count / float(student_count) * 100
print(passing_reading_percentage)
```

I am getting error type : cannot convert the series to a <class 'float'>

Comment: Sounds like `student_count` is a series, not a number.  Where's the code that defines `student_count`?

Comment: `float` is a function that returns one number.  It can't convert a pandas Series to a float `dtype`.  Similarly for numpy array.  There's a difference between `type` and `dtype`

Comment: You can convert all the items in a pandas Series to float using astype().

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have jumped into using `pandas` without reading much of a intro.  And not a lot of python either.

You didn't provide a error traceback. We can guess where the error occurs, but you didn't define the variable(s) in the error.

If I make a simple pandas Series:

```
In [180]: count = pd.Series(np.arange(5))
In [181]: count
Out[181]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64
```

And try to use the python `float` function (take some time to read about it, in a python docs or intro):

```
In [182]: float(count)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [182] in <cell line: 1>
    float(count)
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py:191 in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

That's your error message - with traceback

A `Series` has a `dtype`:

```
In [183]: count.dtype
Out[183]: dtype('int64')
```

We can create a new Series, with a float dtype:

```
In [184]: count1 = count.astype(float)
In [185]: count1
Out[185]: 
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    4.0
dtype: float64
```

In recent enough versions of Python, you don't need to make something a float to do division.  You have to use a special `//` to do integer division.  Both the float and integer Series do the same thing:

```
In [186]: 100/count1
Out[186]: 
0           inf
1    100.000000
2     50.000000
3     33.333333
4     25.000000
dtype: float64
In [187]: 100/count
Out[187]: 
0           inf
1    100.000000
2     50.000000
3     33.333333
4     25.000000
dtype: float64
```

Correct use of the float function:

```
In [190]: float(1)
Out[190]: 1.0
In [191]: float('1.23')
Out[191]: 1.23
```